# Changing the formatting for a time display

Tags: java, android, time, format

I am using the following code to display a timer in my app (in an editText named "time")

```
final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
Long spentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
Long minius = (spentTime/1000)/60;
Long seconds = (spentTime/1000) % 60;
time.setText(minius+":"+seconds);
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

This works well but the formatting is a bit ugly. So for e.g. at 4 seconds the timer shows "0:4" which doesn't really look like a timer.

How do I change the formatting of the setText so that it shows a more usual timer (such as 00:04), without having to make a bunch of if statements (if seconds less than 10 then 0+seconds and so on)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format` to pad the digits with `0`'s:

```
String formattedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", minius, seconds);
time.setText(formattedTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set leading 0's with the `String.format` command. Try:

```
time.setText(String.format("%02d",minius) + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds));
```

That gives always gives you two digits leading with a 0 when it is only one.

Comment: you are missing one parenthesis at the end